# Using the Flask-RESTFUL, how do I implement file/photo uploading in one of the post methods?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I've actually been messing around this for quite some time now following instructions such as, http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/fileuploads/
and even trying to use flask-uploads (I could not import correctly, as it keeps saying I cannot import the extension). So I'm just going to stick with Flask's methods for uploading photos.

Anyways, I figured my Flask-RESTFUL is pretty standard:

```
from flask import make_response, Flask, request, jsonify, redirect, url_for
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource
from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import os


app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://thanks:foryourhelp@localhost'
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '~/Documents/app/static'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])
app.config['UPLOADS_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER



api = Api(app)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()
class uploadPhoto(Resource):
  decorators = [auth.login_required]

  def __init__(self):
    self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
    self.reqparse.add_argument('image', type = str, default="")
    self.reqparse.add_argument('lat', type = float,  default="")
    self.reqparse.add_argument('lon', type = float,  default="")
    super(uploadPhoto, self).__init__()

  def post(self):
    file = request.files['file']
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
      filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
      file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
      return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))



api.add_resource(uploadPhoto, '/uploads/')
```

So I wanted to test it and upload a file using python's Requests library by uploading a photo, and the line of code that's throwing the error is:

```
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
KeyError: 'UPLOAD_FOLDER'
```

Is it because I'm using flaskRESTFUL? I have a different way of setting up the api using resources. Anyways, I'm stuck and would like to get this working, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have `app.config['UPLOADS_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER` and then in your `post` function you use `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']`. You should use `app.config['UPLOADS_FOLDER']`.